# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i can push to heroku just fine.. however when I run a rake i get this error: 
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server

I can run locally ok so not really sure why I am having trouble pushing to heroku - any help would be great

I suspect this is related to my database.yml file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3




production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Also here is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'capistrano'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets

  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
  gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
  gem 'autoprefixer-rails'  
  gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.7'
  gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views



# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not commit database.yml into heroku:

```
When Rails applications are deployed to Heroku a database.yml file is
automatically generated for your application that configures
ActiveRecord to use a PostgreSQL connection and to connect to the
database located at DATABASE_URL. This behavior is only needed up to
Rails 4.1. Any later version contains direct support for specifying a
connection URL and configuration in the database.yml so we do not have
to overwrite it.
```

Read [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) about this.

Comment: How can I not commit this ?

Comment: Rename your database.yml into something else. Commit the change into your repository. This should make your heroku app working. In your root folder you have a .gitignore file.  Edit this file and add /config/database.yml into it. After you modify .gitignore you can rename that file back to database.yml because now it is ignored by git.

Comment: you can give it what extension you desire. Remember to remane it back to database.yml after you commit the change to heroku and add this line /config/database.yml into .gitignore. You must do that in order for your application to work on your local machine.

Comment: It just makes bootloop on Rails 5